# Asignarle un color rgb a un celda de un datagridview

Tags: vb.net

```
row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Red 'RGB(1, 1, 1)
```

El rgb no me lo acepta. Como haría en este caso?

Answer (score 3):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu DataGridView se llama grilla, utiliza lo siguiente:

en el evento RowEnter de tu grilla, escribe

grilla.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(209, 227, 254);